# Python Zeep - Missing element for Any

Tags: python, wsdl, zeep

I have the follow python code used to consume WS using Zeep.

```
date_ = date.today().strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M')  # '2016-08-01 00:00:00'
destination = {'column': 'destination', 'value': destination, 'type': 'string'}
doc_date = {'column': 'doc_date', 'value': date_, 'type': 'string'}
type_id = {'column': 'type_id', 'value': type_id, 'type': 'string'}  # 507
typist = {'column': 'typist', 'value': typist, 'type': 'string'}
priority = {'column': 'priority', 'value': priority, 'type': 'integer'}
data = {'datas': [destination, doc_date, type_id, typist, priority]}

try:
    res = client.service.storeResource(encoded_data, data, collID, table, fileFormat, status)

    if res.returnCode == 0:
        if category == '':
            return True
        mlb_data = {'datas': [{'column': 'category_id', 'value': category, 'type': 'string'}]}
        res2 = client.service.storeExtResource(res.resId, mlb_data, 'mlb_coll_ext')
        return True
    else:
        print("res KO")
        return False
except Exception as e:
    print("SD2:", e)
    return False
```

I test the WS "storeResource" alone with SOAP UI and it's working, with the same parameters. Here is the error I've got after running my python script

```
SD2: Missing element for Any
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to set "Any" parameter when you're calling your service:

```
client.service.storeExtResource(Any='value')
```

Comment: AttributeError: Service has no operation 'storeExtResource'

Answer (score -1):

To resolve the "missing element" error for optional parameters, use the following:

```
from zeep import xsd
```

and set optional element you won't send as `xsd.SkipValue`.